# UITableViewCell separator lines are missing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

The separator lines on my table view are absent from the view. Need suggestions on what may be the cause. I have checked my storyboard and everything seems to check out. The separator and separator color are both set to default.

[image: UITableViewCells]

As for my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:YES];

[self loadObjects];

self->restaurants = [NSArray array];
[self performSelector: @selector(retreiveFromParse)];

[_restaurantTable reloadData];

}

- (void)retreiveFromParse {

PFQuery *retrieveRestaurants = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Restaurants"];

[retrieveRestaurants findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects,     NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        restaurants = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        NSLog(@"successful");

    }
}];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section {

return [self->restaurants count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject*)object
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

  UILabel *title = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1];
title.text = [object objectForKey:@"title"];

  return cell;


}
```

Update: I solved it by simply deleting the [self loadObjects]; line my viewDidLoad method. The separator lines now show in my view !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be of separator color itself .By default it is White

so try changing it to another color either in storyboard or by code itself.

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

When the UITableView is selected in the storyboard, the Separator dropdown should be set to: "Default" or "Single Line"

Comment: Hmmm. Might want to clean and rebuild, and reset Simulator. Note that you don't need to check for nil after dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier if you are using a Storyboard. Also, make sure the Indentation is set to default: Level=0, Width=10

Comment: The indentation was set to a width of 0, however when even when I changed it to 10 it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on simulator for xcode6.1 but it works fine for the device. Have you tried running it on the device?